# Serial port in C++ How do I?

Tags: c++, windows

I want help to write in Serial Port. I use a FTDI cable to 'see' the usb as a serial port.

I gone through the example given in msdn  but I don't understand it.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx  . Is this written in C++/CLI mode? what does  the symbol ^ means?

I get error when I use #using  and lots of errors. If someone can go through a simple code for start only writing to the serial port that would be great!

Comment: Do simple file open of file `\\.\COMn` and read/write then.

Comment: Yes, `^` means it's [C++/CLI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578052/use-of-operator-in-visual-c).

Comment: You shouldn't ask others about writing code for you here. Better show what you've tried, and may be we can help you to fix the errors.

Comment: The .NET SerialPort class is only usable from a .NET project.  Like the kind you find under the CLR node in the project creation dialog.  In native C++ like you are trying to use you'll have to do this the Hard Way™.  Boost's asio can get you somewhere as long as you don't do have to do anything fancy.  Otherwise plenty of libraries around.  Too many, use google.

Answer (score 1):

You can open a handle to a serial port using CreateFile function
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx

use the name "\.\COMx" where x is the com port number